# Pricing of SQL datawarehouse in azure

Tags: azure-synapse

I would like to get a picture of how pricing works in azure for SQL datawarehouse.

Scenario - I have kept the SQL datawarehouse in azure at 6000 DWU , and have not done any inserts/updates/deletes/selects i.e no operations have been done on SQL datawarehouse. So will I be charged the 6000 tier pricing for each day even if no operations has been performed or will I not be charged.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is asking about pricing of a service and is not a programming question.

Answer (score 0):

You will be charged.  Azure SQL Data Warehouse operations are charged based on hours running (ie not in pause state) and depending on what DWU you were running at, as per the pricing page [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/pricing/details/sql-data-warehouse/).  It's kind of expensive to run at DWU 6000 and not do anything.  Why didn't you pause it?

Azure Data Lake Analytics (ADLA) is pay as you go if that's what you are looking for.